# Focused Application Change Event In Windows

Tags: c#, windows, events

I would like to catch as an event each time that the focused application on Windows change, preferently in C#. I need to prevent that my co-workers can send emails from my Outlook account when I stand up.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How is a window focus change event related to you getting up off of your computer chair?

Comment: Ahm, what I'm thinking, is to detect outlook message windows, and lock computer or close windows while my programm is running. Maybe 
I can ask for a password.

Comment: Check my answer below, you can do that too with Windows hooks.

Comment: Protecting only outlook by the way also means the person could install a keylogger on your machine and come back next time you are away from your computer.  Or they could simply kill your process.

Answer (score 3):

Lock your computer, [Windows Key]+L, when you get up.

Comment: Yes, I try to do that, but sometimes I forget it.

Comment: Stop forgetting, its a general joke at our office, whoever leaves their computer unlocked, someone sends an email to the team saying they will bring in donuts the next day, then they have to bring in donuts.

Comment: The same joke here, and what is worse, I have an IBM ThinkPad T43, it doesn't have Windows logo keys.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+DELETE -> Lock Computer

Comment: Change your screen saver to have a short timeout and require a password when you come back.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off tracking idle time of keyboard and mouse via using Windows Hooks.  [Here is a project (CodeProject: Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) to get you started.  You can modify it slightly and get a working version.

You can do something like this once the keyboard and mouse haven't been used for X minutes:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("rundll32.exe");
psi.Arguments = "user32.dll, LockWorkStation";
Process.Start(psi);
```